# Unresolved type in pointer receiver

Tags: go

I have type `Process` in a library called `lib`.

I am trying to import that library and add a method associated with type from `lib` package.

```
func(p *lib.Process) DoSomething(pp *lib.Process)
```

But I have an error `unresolved type 'lib'` inside of `func(...)`. It ls surprising for me, because there is no error inside `DoSomething`.

How is it possible to overcome it?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations "... The type denoted by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be a pointer or interface type and **it must be defined in the same package** as the method. ..."

Comment: Check this solution. It's worked to me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61356467/22522605

Answer (score 17):

You cannot extend types defined in other packages. What you can do, is embed a type in another package in your own type, then extend your own type.  Example:

```
type MyProcess struct {
    lib.Process
}

func (p *MyProcess) DoSomething(...) {
    // ...
}
```

With this method, all of the existing methods on `lib.Process` will still be accessible, as well as your own.

Answer (score 3):

You can't extend existing types in another package. You can define your own type or sub-package as follows.

```
type LibProcess lib.Process

func(p *LibProcess)DoSomething(pp *LibProcess) {}
```

---

**type alias vs defintion**

```
type LibProcess lib.Process // type defintion

type LibProcess = lib.Process // type alias
```

- A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an identifier to it.
- An alias declaration binds an identifier to the given type.

Comment: `LibProcess` is not an [alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) for `lib.Process`.  `LibProcess` is a new type that shares a base type with `lib.Process`. `LibProcess` does have any of the `lib.Process` methods.

Comment: Aliases will not allow this. Only an entirely new type will.

Comment: @ThunderCat Thank you for correcting me, I misunderstand `alias`.

Comment: Type definitions don't inherent methods (which seems to be what you're implying by "and operations").  You need an embed for that.