# Goland shows os.Remove() can't be resolved?

Tags: go, goland

In `Goland` *(2022.1.3)*, using `go` *(1.19.1)*, it can't resolve `os.Remove()`, but if I change to `os.RemoveAll()`, it's ok.

I've checked [go doc](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Remove) and [source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d7dbe0111ef2a6de80a20fef188db61d8fab5c96/src/os/file_unix.go#L305), the function does exists.

So, what's wrong ? Is that a goland bug ?

*(BTW, I'm using linux os, if that matters.)*

---

**Screenshot** *(in Goland)*:

[image: goland pic]

---

**Update:** An example code that can run

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

func main() {
    os.Create("/tmp/a.txt")
    os.Remove("/tmp/a.txt")
}
```

The code can run without error, so I think it's goland's bug.

Comment: It(the function) works?

Comment: @spike014 Yes, it can run successfully. I've added an example.

Comment: Have you tried [File -> Invalidate Caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/invalidate-caches.html) and restarting (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61356467/11810946))?.

Comment: If you use IntelliJ with the Go plugin instead of Goland, the solution is the same as the answer but you have to upgrade Intellij first. It will prompt you to update the plugins at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go introduces a new build tag `unix` in Go 1.19, but GoLand lower than 2022.2 doesn't support it natively.

- Update GoLand to 2022.2.3.
- Alternatively, add `unix` build tag in *Preferences/Settings | Go | Build Tags & Vendoring | Custom tags*.

If you use IntelliJ with the Go plugin, make sure to upgrade IntelliJ to 2022.2 or above first. It will prompt to upgrade the plugins at the same time.

Comment: Adding `unix` build tag, then it worked immediately.